# Persisted column using default value rather than inserted value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was playing with computed columns and I noticed some weird behaviour with persisted computed columns.

The query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp 
(
    ExternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    UniqueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT(NEWID()),
    --Id AS ISNULL(ExternalId, UniqueId),
    PersistedId AS ISNULL(ExternalId, UniqueId) PERSISTED
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (ExternalId) 
VALUES (null), (NEWID())

SELECT * FROM #tmp

UPDATE #tmp
SET externalid = CASE WHEN ExternalId IS NULL THEN newid() ELSE null END

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

If you run this, you get the following output:

**Just Persisted**

Select 1:

| ExternalId | UniqueId | PersistedId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | fb544e9e-7d9b-47ec-b2ca-45484e02e343 | fb544e9e-7d9b-47ec-b2ca-45484e02e343 |
| c6b3b82a-db68-46e4-8cfe-a4a0eedad2cf | 56d0091f-0f08-49f3-a020-f73fd2074d7a | 3fc603ce-dcac-449e-8f0a-203cfda0a634 |

Select 2:

| ExternalId | UniqueId | PersistedId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0ecdff52-a59c-421f-bf87-8938488b83ea | fb544e9e-7d9b-47ec-b2ca-45484e02e343 | 0ecdff52-a59c-421f-bf87-8938488b83ea |
| NULL | 56d0091f-0f08-49f3-a020-f73fd2074d7a | 56d0091f-0f08-49f3-a020-f73fd2074d7a |

You can see that the persisted column for select 1 has a different guid to that of the external id.

Now if I uncomment the `Id` line from the `CREATE TABLE` statement and run it again I get the following:

**Both**

Select 1:

| ExternalId | UniqueId | Id | PersistedId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1275aff9-0c59-4406-8bd5-ae694d228a6d | 1275aff9-0c59-4406-8bd5-ae694d228a6d | 1275aff9-0c59-4406-8bd5-ae694d228a6d |
| 4b7ac3d8-ad3e-4e94-b8df-c464b99e630c | e7980647-fe4f-45a2-9d41-53da0b8d780f | 4b7ac3d8-ad3e-4e94-b8df-c464b99e630c | 4b7ac3d8-ad3e-4e94-b8df-c464b99e630c |

Select 2:

| ExternalId | UniqueId | Id | PersistedId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d606ea7b-f17b-48d8-8581-82c8736bf61f | 1275aff9-0c59-4406-8bd5-ae694d228a6d | d606ea7b-f17b-48d8-8581-82c8736bf61f | d606ea7b-f17b-48d8-8581-82c8736bf61f |
| NULL | e7980647-fe4f-45a2-9d41-53da0b8d780f | e7980647-fe4f-45a2-9d41-53da0b8d780f | e7980647-fe4f-45a2-9d41-53da0b8d780f |

As you can see with this, now that the id is also getting computed the PersistedId get's the correct id. I've also tried on the "Just Persisted" inserting a static guid and it looks fine, so I'm assuming the persisted column is calling the newid() again from the insert statement. Does anyone know the work around for this and whether?

I can't imagine the externalid in the main project *(that this example code is for)* would have a newid() used in a insert a new record, but I can't say it'll never happen.

**UPDATE**

This does seem to be a bug and not a PICNIC problem, so I've opened a Microsoft Bug: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/4611e2d2-1fd3-ee11-92bc-6045bd7aea25

Comment: Why do you want/need to use `PERSISTED` here? If it's to make the column better for queries, why not `INDEX` it? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QCONQ5Xj)

Comment: In truth, this reads like a bug report than anything, and reporting bugs for products isn't what [so] is for.

Comment: It doesn't need to be persisted, this is just my first time using it and so I was playing with it (I was trying it for potential other uses in the future). As for whether it is a bug or not, I've never used them before and so I wasn't quite sure if it was a bug or not (thought I may have just misread or not read the part which covered this)

Comment: I think, expression ``ISNULL(ExternalId, UniqueId)`` in your case - ``insert`` - is not deterministic. But ``persisted`` column must be deterministic.

Comment: Another example https://dbfiddle.uk/_ct7_oRW

Comment: Bug previously reported on Connect and migrated to new feedback site https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a1040494-5f25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 2):

I agree, I think it is a bug a well.  It appears to have something to do with the NEWID() function, as the problem goes away when I assign an ID to a variable:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp

Declare @ID UniqueIdentifier = NEWID();

CREATE TABLE #tmp 
(
    ExternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    UniqueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT(NEWID()),
    --Id AS ISNULL(ExternalId, UniqueId),
    PersistedId AS ISNULL(ExternalId, UniqueId) PERSISTED
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (ExternalId) 
VALUES (null), (@ID)

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Another way the problem goes away is when you divide the insert statement into two commands.

```
INSERT INTO #tmp (ExternalId) 
VALUES (null)

INSERT INTO #tmp (ExternalId) 
VALUES  (NEWID())
```

Interesting!

Update:  There is a similar article that describes the issue:

[Inconsistent results with NEWID() and PERSISTED computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120684/inconsistent-results-with-newid-and-persisted-computed-column)

This does not work:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    Col1 INT,
    Contains2 AS CASE WHEN 2 IN (Col1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED)

INSERT INTO @test (Col1) VALUES
    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5)),
    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5)),
    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5)),
    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5)),
    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5))

SELECT * FROM @test
UPDATE @test SET Col1 = Col1*1
SELECT * FROM @test
```

...but when I divied the inserts into individual commands, it works!

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    Col1 INT,
    Contains2 AS CASE WHEN 2 IN (Col1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED)
    
INSERT INTO @test (Col1) VALUES    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5))
INSERT INTO @test (Col1) VALUES    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5))
INSERT INTO @test (Col1) VALUES    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5))
INSERT INTO @test (Col1) VALUES    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5))
INSERT INTO @test (Col1) VALUES    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5))

select * from @test
```

...please read the other article, they did a great job describing the problem.